# How to take the semi last value per group

Tags: pandas, filter

I would like per group to keep the semi-last value, as indicated below.

```
ID number    
1   50    
1   49    
1   48
1   45    
2   47    
2   40    
2   31    
3   60    
3   51
```

Example output

```
1  48

2  40

3  60
```

Comment: `df.groupby('ID')['number'].nth(-2)` ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One liner:

```
df[df[::-1].groupby('ID').cumcount()[::-1]==1]
```

Output:

```
   ID  number
2   1      48
5   2      40
7   3      60
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Groupby.nth`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html) with `-2` :

```
df.groupby('ID')['number'].nth(-2)
```

[out]

```
ID
1    48
2    40
3    60
Name: number, dtype: int64
```